# ASP.NET 5 Web API not loading References

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I just created a new Project "**Web API**" in the Section "**ASP.NET 5** Preview Templates" and after the scaffolding, it says that
some references didnt load:

[image]

Do you know how to fix that? I'm using **Visual Studio 2015**.

Comment: Right-cliick on "References" node and select "Restore packages" context menu item. Wait until packages will be restored - and you've done. If this will not help - do exactly what Visual Studio tells you at references node title - have a look to "Errors list" window (the same window where you're seeing compilation errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Potential issues

This is caused by one of two things in my experience:

1. project.lock.json being out of date;
2. The Dot Net Version Manager (DNVM) being set to a different version of the framework than your project.

## Fixes:

If it is potential issue 1 (project.lock.json out of date), try a full refresh on it:

1. Delete project.lock.json from the same folder as your *.xproj file using some file manager outside VS;
2. Open a command prompt in the folder (assuming windows explorer: shift+right click -> Open command window here);
3. Run `dnx restore`;
4. Try to rebuild your project.

If that didn't work, or you got a message about runtime target frameworks, steps for potential issue 2 are:

1. In VS, open your *.xproj properties (alt+enter) and note the Solution DNX SDK version:

[image: Version number]

2. Open a command prompt in the folder (assuming windows explorer: shift+right click -> Open command window here);
3. Run `dnvm list`:

   ```
   C:\Users\vagrant\gitlab\FirstLookAspNet5\Messenger\src\Messenger>dnvm list
   Active Version           Runtime Architecture Location                       Alias
   ------ -------           ------- ------------ --------                       -----
          1.0.0-beta4       clr     x86          C:\Users\vagrant\.dnx\runtimes
          1.0.0-beta5       clr     x64          C:\Users\vagrant\.dnx\runtimes
          1.0.0-beta5       clr     x86          C:\Users\vagrant\.dnx\runtimes
          1.0.0-beta5       coreclr x64          C:\Users\vagrant\.dnx\runtimes
          1.0.0-beta5       coreclr x86          C:\Users\vagrant\.dnx\runtimes
          1.0.0-beta6       clr     x86          C:\Users\vagrant\.dnx\runtimes
          1.0.0-beta7       clr     x64          C:\Users\vagrant\.dnx\runtimes
     *    1.0.0-beta7       clr     x86          C:\Users\vagrant\.dnx\runtimes default
          1.0.0-beta7       coreclr x86          C:\Users\vagrant\.dnx\runtimes
          1.0.0-beta8-15654 clr     x86          C:\Users\vagrant\.dnx\runtimes
          1.0.0-rc1-15798   clr     x86          C:\Users\vagrant\.dnx\runtimes
   ```
4. You'll probably see a discrepancy between the version in your project and the one highlighted by the asterisk. I imagine you're building using intellisense so you'll probably want to set your dnvm to the same version as VS is using.  So in my example I'd do:

   ```
   > dnvm use 1.0.0-beta4
   Adding C:\Users\vagrant\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta4\bin to process PATH
   ```
5. run `dnx restore` or restore packages in VS again

Hope that helps.